# Hyphen in Anti-malware but not Antivirus

Tags: hyphenation

Why is there a hyphen in Anti-malware but not a hyphen in antivirus. I have found nothing, no matter how far I have searched hence my presence on this site.

Comment: Compare [this "anti-malware" NGram](https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=antimalware%2Canti-malware&year_start=1990&year_end=2008&corpus=15&smoothing=3&share=&direct_url=t1%3B%2Cantimalware%3B%2Cc0%3B.t1%3B%2Canti%20-%20malware%3B%2Cc0) with [this "anti-virus" chart](https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=antivirus%2Canti-virus&year_start=1990&year_end=2008&corpus=15&smoothing=3&share=&direct_url=t1%3B%2Cantivirus%3B%2Cc0%3B.t1%3B%2Canti%20-%20virus%3B%2Cc0). Common hyphenated forms tend to become "fused" after a while. It's just that ***antivirus*** has been around longer.

Comment: Please (as ELU expects) give the linked references to the places you _have_ tried, to save other visitors the senseless task of repeating fruitless searches.  Does no dictionary list anti-virus say as an alternative? Suggestions are (a) hyphens often disappear as a new compound gets older and more familiar, and 'antivirus' is a lot older; (b) 'antimalware' looks a little outlandish, with no hint as to where syllables divide.

Comment: I think this is an interesting question. My dictionary (Pocket Oxford) hyphenates _anti-abortion, anti-aircraft, anti-hero, anti-lock, anti-nuclear, anti-Semite_ and _anti-tank_ out of nearly 40 'anti-' words (not including _anti-malware_). I agree with Edwin that some would look odd without the hyphen, but why, for instance _anti-lock_ but _antiknock_?

Comment: Dictionaries are not consistent: The on-line Oxford gives "antivirus", while the Cambridge gives "anti-virus". "Anti-malware" hasn't become lexicalised, at least not yet, hence no entry for it in either of those dictionaries, and yet "antimatter" (no hyphen) has.

Answer (score 3):

Hyphenation of affixes (in English, usually prefixes and suffixes) is arbitrary, in the sense that it comes down to style guides and conventions of usage, rather than a single consistent set of rules. For example, here is the advice given in APA and Chicago:

**[APA](https://blog.apastyle.org/apastyle/2016/10/hyphenation-station-the-hyphenation-of-prefixes-in-apa-style.html)**:

> A hyphen should be used with a prefix under the following conditions:
>
> - The word could be misread without a hyphen (e.g., re-pair, meaning to pair again, vs. repair, meaning to fix).
> - The double vowels aa, ii, oo, or uu would occur without a hyphen (e.g., anti-intellectual is correct, not antiintellectual).
> - The word that follows the hyphen is capitalized (e.g., un-American).
> - The word that follows the hyphen begins with a numeral (e.g., mid-2016).
> - The word is shown as permanently hyphenated in Merriam-Webster’s dictionary (e.g., pro-choice).
> - A prefix is being added to a compound word that is already hyphenated (e.g., adding post- to graduate-level students creates
>     post-graduate-level students, but if the phrase is just graduate
>     students [no hyphen] then adding post- as a prefix gives you the
>     regular hyphenless postgraduate students).

**[Chicago](https://www.chicagomanualofstyle.org/16/ch07/ch07_sec085.html)**:

> Compounds formed with prefixes are normally closed, whether they are nouns, verbs, adjectives, or adverbs. A hyphen should appear, however, (1) before a capitalized word or a numeral, such a[s] *sub-Saharan, pre-1950*; (2) before a compound term, such as *non-self-sustaining, pre-Vietnam War* (before an open compound, an en-dash is used; see 6.80); (3) to separate two i's, two-a's, and other combinations of letters or syllables that might cause misreading, such as *anti-intellectual, extra-alkaline, pro-life*;  (4) to separate the repeated terms in a double-prefix, such as *sub-subentry*; (5) when a prefix or combining form stands alone, such as *over-* and *underused*, *macro-* and *microeconomics*. The spellings shown below conform largely to Merriam-Webster's Collegiate Dictionary."

In this case, both style guides illustrate two possible explanations for *anti-malware* but *antivirus* in their formats:

1. To limit misreading. Because *mal* is already an abbreviation of *malicious*, *-ware* is already a suffix, and *malware* is a relatively new word, *antimalware* has a greater probability of being misread or mispronounced. (Ex. *antimal-ware*.) The hyphen clarifies the root from the prefix/suffix. *Virus*, being a well-known word with no other affixes, is less likely to be misread without a hyphen.
2. To conform to standard use in dictionaries. *Anti-malware* usually does not appear in dictionaries, and this includes Merriam-Webster, the dictionary of choice for APA and Chicago. Antivirus does, in [unhyphenated form](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/antivirus).

In addition, affixes tend to join their words and become unhyphenated over time if the words are often used. *Antivirus* has been a word since 1892, according to [Merriam-Webster](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/antivirus), is used in two distinct fields (medicine and computing), and many users are familiar with the word. *Malware* has been a word since about [1990](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/malware), which means *anti-malware* is still newer, and perhaps hasn't become familiar enough to drop the hyphen.

So that's three possible explanations for hyphenation. Two, preventing misreading and aligning with dictionary documentation, are general guidelines a style guide might suggest to create consistency. The third, the progression of time making formerly-hyphenated words familiar enough to omit the hyphen, is an arbitrary phenomenon that admits exceptions.

Comment: I didn't give an 'answer' as I considered the question in need of improvement, and that this has all been said before. However. I think that this answer ties the hyphenation issue together more thoroughly and clearly than (separate) previous ones have done.